# Why did detected pause in JVM or host machine warning reported frequently in Apache IoTDB while the system is still running?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Have anyone ever encountered situation which lots of warning message in Apache IoTDB monitor was reported, stating that IoTDB to pause? I currently use Version 1.1.0, and there's frequent message like `WARN o.a.r.u.JvmPauseMonitor:126 - JvmPauseMonitor-1: Detected pause in JVM or host machine: pause of approximately 751730735 ns` informed. Since this warning is frequently reported, but the system is still activated and running, I want to know are there any adjustment I need to do? I checked the guide and questions already asked, but still did not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is due to GC monitoring of Apache IoTDB. From your pausing period, it seems like the problem should not be serious. If you are frequently receiving this warning, you can consider to upgrade to the new version (1.3+), because the monitoring threshold in the new version has been increased and there will no longer be printing this warning so much.